Vernacular (colloquial) pronunciations of the letter 'w'
I went thoroughly over Ortografía de la lengua española (2010, RAE), specifically sections §6.1.2.2.2 and §6.2.2.1.2, and came up with the following summary of pronunciation rules for the letter 'w'. (Note that I use // to indicate a phoneme sequence and [] to indicate a more narrow IPA transcription. For the former I'm also using IPA symbols, unlike the RAE document, which eg writes /laurénzio/ where I would write /lau'renθio/ and [law'ɾenθjo] for the European pronunciation of "laurencio"/"lawrencio" [2 spellings] (lawrencium, chemical element 103Lr).)

/(g)u/ (exceptionally: /b/): (1) in most words of English origin, (2) in certain terms transcribed into the Latin alphabet from Eastern, Semitic, or indigenous languages, many of which were also introduced through English, and (3) in geographical and personal names

[gw]/[ɣw]: syllable-initially and not adjacent to the phoneme /u/:
Darwin [incl: darwinismo, darwinista], Hawái [incl: hawaiano/-a], kiwi, sándwich [gw]/[dw], sawali, Taiwán [incl: taiwanés/-esa], Wahid, wasabi, Washington [incl: washingtoniano/-a], wáter (LatAm variant of váter), waterpolo, watt, wau, web, wellingtonia, peso wélter, wéstern, WhatsApp, wifi, wiki, wiski
[w]: non-syllable-initially [syllable-final 'w' seems to never be adjacent to the phoneme /u/]:
lawrencio, Rawson [incl: rawsense], taekwondo [kw]
[b]/[β]: adjacent to the phoneme /u/:
Hollywood [incl: hollywood(i)ense], Kuwait [incl: kuwaití], Wuhan, Wurzburgo


[b]/[β]:

Visigothic names:
Wamba, Wifredo, Witiza
from German (also [v]):
Ludwig, Wagner [incl: wagneriano/-a], Weimar [incl: weimarés/-esa], wesen, Westfalia [incl: westfaliano/-a], Wittenberg, wolframio
geographical and personal names from other European languages [both examples below are surnames]:
Kowalski, van der Weyden



Note that the lists above contain all words listed in the respective sections of the text and were supplemented by data from Wikipedia's Spanish orthography article and other sources.
Now to my question. The above represents the RAE's prescriptions (which in fact appear to be quite linguistically descriptive), but: How do ordinary people in Spain and Latin America pronounce the 'w' in these words? Do they really generally follow the scheme by the RAE?
Rationales for my question:

When asking a native speaker about the pronunciation of some words, their answer sounded like the second high-level bullet point ("[b]/[β]" for Visigothic names, words from German, and names from other European languages) would need some refinement, perhaps like this:


[b]/[β] (Sp prescriptive); /(g)u/ (Sp colloquial); [w] (LatAm):

Visigothic names: [...]
from German (also [v]): [...]
geographical and personal names from other European languages: [...]




That is, they said that instead of /b/ ([b]/[β]) ordinary Spaniards would most likely pronounce this like "(g)u", and people in Latin America would most likely say [w] (like in English). However, I am not sure whether I understood their statement correctly, and I also don't know whether it was only meant to apply to words which a native speaker hasn't encountered before.

I also did some own research, mostly by checking on YouGlish, and I found some discrepancies or special cases, which I'm not sure how to judge (because I'm a learner):

WhatsApp: Sp [watsap] (less commonly with [gw] or with [s]-instead-of-[ts]; both syllables can be stressed); LatAm [gwat'sap]
wifi: Sp ['gwifi] (less commonly ['wifi]); LatAm ['(g)waifai] (less commonly [(g)wai'fai])
Weimar: ['bej], ['vaj], ['gwej]
Volkswagen: ['folzvaɣen], [volz'vaɣen]

The last word here (Volkswagen) isn't in the large list above; it doesn't seem to follow RAE rules.


Note: For Latin American usage, I am slightly more interested in Mexico and Argentina, but I welcome information about all places.

TLDR: No te compliques ni te preocupes mucho. Si conocés la etimología pronunciala según corresponda, sinó mandá simplemente /w/, /gw/, o incluso /u/, cualquiera va a ir bien.
La doble ve no la consideraría una letra propiamente del español; más bien diría que la incluímos en el alfabeto porque necesitamos adaptar palabras que vinieron de otros idiomas, fundamentalmente del inglés, alemán pero también de idiomas nativos americanos.
Otros idiomas, como el italiano o el alemán son mucho más puristas: el hábito es mantener las palabras extranjeras como prestamos ‘en crudo’, esto es, manteniendo la pronunciación y la grafía original. Nosotros en general no somos tan exigentes, más bien diría que las pronunciamos como nos quede cómodo o como podemos, y en algunos casos si es necesario inventamos una grafía diferente para ayudarnos. En España llevan esta máxima más al extremo que en América, quizá por la influencia de la Academia.
Pero bueno, lo cierto es que con la doble ve no nos preocupamos mucho. Si sirve, a mí lo único que me enseñaron en su momento es que se pronuncia:

Como /b/ (también iría /v/, pero no tiene sentido ya que no es un fonema normativo del castellano) cuando está al principio de ciertas palabras de origen alemán como ‘wolframio’ (/bol'fɾamio/), o también en nombres alemanes como Wagner, etc.
En todos los demás casos, se pronuncia de forma ‘natural’.

Así y todo, muchas veces escuché cosas como /wol'fɾamio/ o /'wagner/ y nunca vi a nadie corrigiendo pronunciación por esto; en mi opinión ya está aceptado, aunque sea tácitamente, que son las versiones castellanizadas de esas palabras alemanas.
Por ‘natural’ se entiende /w/, /gw/ o incluso /u/, porque salvo que alguien te preste mucha atención nadie va a notar la diferencia. Tomando una palabra cualquiera, ‘whisky’, lo más común sería /'wiski/ o /'gwiski/ pero en algunos casos raros también /u'iski/. Lo mismo con palabras que empiezan con hu- como ‘huevo’, puede ser /'webo/, /'gwebo/, o incluso /u'ebo/. Todos alófonos, nadie se preocupa demasiado ni tiene sentido establecer una distinción.
EDIT
A pedido del OP, información extra acerca de cómo uno podría saber o predecir cuándo la doble ve pierde su sonido ‘natural’. Como ya dije, no queda otra que conocer la etimología. Para esto es útil Wikipedia (también el Wikcionario), sobre todo el sitio en inglés que suele tener más completa la parte de la pronunciación.
Entonces, supongamos que quisiera adaptar la palabra ‘wronskiano’. Para eso, busco la página de Wronsky, y veo que el apellido se pronuncia [ˈvrɔj̃skʲi]. De acá es donde me doy cuenta de que la mejor forma de aproximarlo en castellano sería /'bɾons.ki/. Finalmente, deduzco que ‘wronskiano’ se pronuncia /bɾons'kia.no/.
Obviamente esto sería la versión ‘purista’ de los hechos porque como ya dije, si veo a alguien pronunciando /wɾons'kia.no/, no es alguien a quien calificaría como ‘que no sabe hablar’ sino más bien diría ‘que no sabe o se olvidó la etimología de esa palabra puntual’. Esto de olvidarse es más que común cuando la grafía no concuerda. Por supuesto, de más está decir que si se trata de una persona que tengo en frente, nunca está de más preguntarle cómo se pronuncia su apellido.
Por cierto, lo de /'xo.li.bud/ fue algo de lo que me enteré cuando vi esta pregunta; yo toda la vida escuché y dije /'xo.li.wud/ y nunca nadie me recriminó nada.

Could you try to tell me what "ordinary average" people say in the {"Visigothic names" / "from German" / "names from other European languages"}-case, [w] or [gw]? I am interested mainly in: Spain, Mexico, Argentina.

@LoverofStructure https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/pronunciacion-de-la-w-1032/, quizá esto ayude un poco. En algunos casos, la tendencia es /gw/, como Waterpolo o Washington, también Winchester. Como decía en mi respuesta, /b/ al comienzo de algunos nombres o palabras de origen germánico, que incluye a Wamba en la lista /'bamba/, y también incluiría a Wronsky o a wronskiano /brons'kiano/.

@LoverofStructure Menciona también lo de la /b/ ([β]) entre medio en casos muy muy  excepcionales, como en Hollywood /'xolibud/ o Kuwait /ku'bait', algo que bien mencionabas en tu pregunta. Por mi parte, yo siempre dije y escuché /'xoliwud/ y /ku'wait/, y nunca tuve problema con eso ni nadie me corrijió nada. En general, nadie conoce tanto la etimología de las palabras, y ante la duda o a falta de información lo normal es pronunciar /w/, siendo /gw/ más común al principio de la palabra.

Como dije, son válidos /w/ /gw/ o también /u/ para los pocos que no pronuncian los diptongos. No sé en el resto de países, pero acá en Argentina no está para nada mal visto pronunciar la "w" como /w/ en lugar de /b/, en esos casos raros. Incluso los que saben las etimologías a menudo se las olvidan, por lo que pasa a ser un desatino muy permisible incluso para los nativos.

Si así y todo te interesa respetar la pronunciación ‘purista’ a rajatabla, te conviene buscar en Wikipedia los nombres. Por ejemplo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B3zef_Maria_Hoene-Wro%C5%84ski para Wronski se ve [ˈvrɔj̃skʲi], de donde se deduce que sería /'bronski/. El sitio en inglés está más completo que el de español con la parte de las pronunciaciones, y de saber la pronunciación original del nombre, se conoce la etimología y se infiere cuál sería la mejor adaptación al castellano. Lo mismo pasa con muchos nombres franceses, como el de Antoine Lavoisier /labwa'seɾ/

Many thanks! Would you like to edit this into your answer? However I have three notes: (1) The "Fundeu" link was already taken into account in my question; we probably don't need to mention that again. (2) The "wronskiano" example is great (but it's Polish, not Germanic). (3) "Lavoisier" as an example doesn't fit, because it uses the letter 'v', not 'w'.
